# Device error: adb.exe: device 'pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28' not found

Tags: android-emulator

When I am debugging the visual studio project, facing this error "Device error: adb.exe: device 'pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28' not found".

Comment: I have the same error making impossible to develop mobile app for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Running VS in admin mode and recreating the emulator (for 64 bits) has worked for me after a few days searching for a solution.